# Javascript regex test from variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an problem with constructing regex from variable.

```
var a = '.playlist-item:nth-child(2n+1)';
var selector = /.playlist-item:nth-child\(2n\+1\)/g;
var s = '.playlist-item:nth-child\(2n\+1\)';

console.log(selector.test(a))//true

var reg = new RegExp(s,"g");
console.log(reg.test(a) )//false
```

Second is false because I have string quotes around it (I think), how do I construct regexp from string?

https://jsfiddle.net/eq3eu2e8/1/

Comment: You have to use double-\ in the regular expression string: `'.playlist-item:nth-child\\(2n\\+1\\)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a string you have to use double backslashes if you want to include them in the string:

```
var a = '.playlist-item:nth-child(2n+1)';
var selector = /.playlist-item:nth-child\(2n\+1\)/g;
var s = '.playlist-item:nth-child\\(2n\\+1\\)';

console.log(selector.test(a)); //true

var reg = new RegExp(s,"g");
console.log(reg.test(a)); //false
```